# What's the difference between alloca(n) and char x[n]?

Tags: c, objective-c, objective-c++, alloca

What is the difference between

```
void *bytes = alloca(size);
```

and

```
char bytes[size];  //Or to be more precise, char x[size]; void *bytes = x;
```

...where *size* is a variable whose value is unknown at compile-time.

Comment: The answer depends critically on whether `size` a compile-time constant. Is it?

Comment: no, size is, for all intents and purposes, an argument to the function

Comment: That doesn't matter.  Apple, by default, uses `--std=gnu99` which supports both.  `alloca()` is a GNU extension, and the variable length array is a standards-compliant C99 feature.

Comment: @Matt B.:What does Apple have to do with any of this?

Comment: @Billy: The question is tagged `objective-c`.  I know that Mac development is not the only use of Obj-C, but that's the most likely application of the language.  My point was that `size` need not be constant with C99/gnu99, and that it is a default mode in Xcode.  A minor (slightly unrelated) correction to my previous comment would be s/Apple/Xcode/.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`alloca()` does not reclaim memory until the current function ends, while the variable length array reclaims the memory when the current block ends.

Put another way:

```
void foo()
{
    size_t size = 42;
    if (size) {
        void *bytes1 = alloca(size);
        char bytes2[size];
    } // bytes2 is deallocated here
}; //bytes1 is deallocated here
```

`alloca()` can be supported (in a fashion) on any C89 compiler, while the variable length array requires a C99 compiler.

Comment: @Billy: the memory allocated by char bytes[size] is not guaranteed to be physically reclaimed at the end of current block; however the access after the current block is not possible anymore.

Comment: @Vlad: Technically the C standard mentions very little about where things actually need to be physically stored to avoid any possible dependency on a particular architecture. However, even if something is not in the standard explicitly, the implicit meaning in the standard results in 99.9% of compilers implementing it that way.

Comment: Good Answer Billy :). Liked it.

Answer (score 6):

From the [GNU documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html):

> Space allocated with alloca exists until the containing *function* returns. The space for a variable-length array is deallocated as soon as the array name's *scope* ends. (If you use both variable-length arrays and alloca in the same function, deallocation of a variable-length array will also deallocate anything more recently allocated with alloca.)

Additionally, `alloca` is not a standard C function, so support is not guaranteed across all compilers. Variable length arrays are part of the C99 standard, so any C99-supporting compiler should implement it.

Comment: Even if it's not supported by your compiler, there are usually public domain versions of `alloca` available.

Comment: VLAs were made optional in C11.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the point Billy mentioned, `alloca` is non-standard (it's not even in C99).

Answer (score 0):

In the second form, `size` must be a constant known to compile time.

Comment: Possibly, but it's more likely the OP is referring to variable length arrays, part of the C99 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the already-discussed points of when exactly the space is freed, and whether the construct is supported at all, there is also this:

- In the `alloca` case, `bytes` has a pointer type.
- In the `[]` case, `bytes` has an array type.

The most noticeable difference is in what `sizeof(bytes)` is; for a pointer it is the size of the pointer (`sizeof(void *)`) whereas for an array it is the size of the allocated space (`sizeof(char) * size`, which = `size` for this case since `sizeof(char)` = 1).

(Also, in your example, the element types are different; to be the same, the first should be changed to  `char *bytes = alloca(size)`.)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference is that alloca does not call constructors or destructors when you are using the memory as class variables.

The other differences are less likely to be noticed, but can become apparent in some weird run time errors in some situations.