# C : How to make the size of an array dynamic?

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2013, c99, c11

I read from book: «C Primer Plus» that tells me in C99 standard, it is ok to use grammar such as:

```
    int b=4;
    char a[b];
```

But when I put this code into vs2013 it tells me the "expression must have a constant value".

Is the book wrong? Or there is some new feature about vs2013 that I wasn't aware of?

Comment: `malloc` is typically used to dynamically size an array.

Comment: Visual Studio is famous for not supporting C properly.

Comment: VS2013 is not a C compiler.

Comment: Microsoft still only supports C89/C90, not C99 and not C11.

Comment: Microsoft currently supports a subset of the C99 standard in Visual Studio 2013 and variable length arrays is one of the missing pieces.  You may use C Preprocessor defines if this is a compile time known size or a memory allocation (`malloc()`, `alloc()`, etc.) if run time sizing is required.  See also this [why is alloca not considered good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-alloca-not-considered-good-practice)

Comment: @Leushenko Can you recommend me an IDE for windows?

Comment: Also I understand that variable length array allocation can fail if there is insufficient stack space similar to what can happen with the `alloc()` function.

Comment: @RichardChambers the C standard does not cover stack overflow at all (whether it be via VLA or otherwise)

Comment: @ArcherJohn personally I prefer lightweight text editors to big IDEs. Try something like Jedit or Geany or Notepad++ if you don't like Eclipse. Get MinGW separately.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I did not mention anything about what the C standard says about stack overflow.  What I did say is that a VLA allocation with a function, which will go onto the stack, may cause a stack overflow according to what I have read such as this stack overflow question [what's the point of VLA anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530363/whats-the-point-of-vla-anyway)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called [Variable Length Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), and I guess that your VS2013 compiler don't support them.

I would advise you to switch to another compiler. Recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or of [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) support VLAs, and they support [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) and even most of [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29).

<sup>Actually I would even suggest to switch your development efforts and system to [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux). Development tools are then usually [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), as the whole system.</sup>

Otherwise, use a pointer, e.g. obtained from [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) (or `calloc`); but then, you should test the allocation against failure and later call `free`. Avoid [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) (use some tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available). Maybe your compiler supports the non-standard but widely available [alloca(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html). Consider perhaps also using *program-wide* a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) like [Boehm's convervative GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/): you'll then use `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` but you won't need to call `GC_free` !

Comment: I was trying to get used to the eclipse in linux, but just can't get used to it. And there are some people recommend me vim editor. That is even worse, I don't even know how to use that

Comment: You could just use `emacs` or `gedit` or `geany` (or many other editors) under Linux.

Comment: I am just a beginner... I have no clue how to use those plain editors... I think I am better to stay with IDEs

Answer (score -1):

VS2013 don't support variable length declaration.

You can't enter a non-constant value between the brackets when you declare your array:

```
char a[b];
```

Since you're getting size from the user, the compiler can't tell ahead of time how much memory it needs for `char array a`. The easiest thing to do here (especially for an exercise) is to just choose a relatively large value and make that the constant allocation, like:

char a[1024];

And then if you want to be careful (and you should) you can check if (b > 1024) and print an error if the user wants `b` that's beyond the pre-allocated bounds.

If you want to get fancy, you can define `char a[]` with no pre-set size, like `char *a;` and then you allocate it later with malloc:

```
a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * b);
```

Then you must also free `char a[]` later, when you're done with it:

```
free(a);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @ArcherJohn you didn't get this?

Comment: I mean I am still learning C right now, I have not gone through that part yet

Comment: @ArcherJohn ohh, okay read this once http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-the-functions-malloc-and-free !

Comment: `a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * b);` Hmmm.  Any particular reason for that over simpler `a = malloc(b);` or `a = malloc(b * sizeof*a);`?

Comment: @chux nope, now it's became a habit of declaring array like this! Should I mention or edit my answer?

Comment: All 3 are functionally the same so it is a style choice - your choice here.  I find `a = malloc(b * sizeof*a);` best to code, understand and maintain.  I like the `b * sizeof*a` vs `sizeof*a * b` as it mimics `calloc(nelem, elem_size)`.

Comment: @chux +1 for reminding me this methods! Thank you! It'll save my time in competitions!

Comment: -1, `char a[]` and `char*a` are not the same. You have to read up the basics about arrays and pointers and how they differ in C.