# Array elements of struct and struct members

Tags: c, struct

I want to ask about a struct declaration in C. For example,

```
struct Person
{
    char name[50];
    int citNo;
    float salary;
} prsn[20];
```

What does `[20]` do? What does it mean? Does it limit the name to 20 (from 50) or limit the `prsn` from `prsn[1]` to `prsn[20]`?

And if I write the code like this:

```
struct Person
{
    char name[50];
    int citNo;
    float salary;
};
struct Person prsn[20];
```

Does it do the same thing?

Comment: They are the same: both declare an array of `20` elements of type `struct Person`

Comment: It is like `int prsn[20];` except with struct Person instead of int

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *What does [20] do? What does it mean?*

The comments below show [common nomenclature for the parts of your struct](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures):

```
struct Person {    //struct name (Person)
    char name[50]; // \
    int citNo;     //  --struct members 
    float salary;  // /
} prsn[20];        // instance of struct Person array
```

The `[20]` indicates that this instance of `struct Person` is an array of 20 separate collections of the 3 members.  Each element of the array can be accessed using array notation.  For example, in a loop:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)// note i goes from 0 to 19
    {
        //.....
        //assuming members have been populated
        printf( "%d)\nName is: %d\ncitNo is: %d salary is: %f\n\n", prsn[i].name, prsn[i].citNo, prsn[i].salary);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> *Does the [20] limit the name to 20 (from 50) or limit the `prsn` from `prsn[1]` to `prsn[20]`?*

The member `name[50]` defines a 50 char array.  Its size is not affected in any way by the `[20]` index used to size the array of struct.  i.e. as you have it defined, there are 20 instances of `prsn`, each instance containing 3 members:  `char [50]`, `int` and `float`.  And by your definition, the 20 instances created by the `[20]` allows the array to be accessed with index values from `0` through `19`. (See loop illustration above.)

*EDIT* to address OP question in comments:

> *And what i have to do if i want to make the elements unlimited ?*

If you want to use the empty array brackets, ( `[]` ) the definition must include a [struct initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization). For example:

```
... } prsn[] = {{"Bill", 1, 23000.00}, {"John", 2, 45000.00}, ...};
```

If the size of the struct array is not known at compile time, and needs to be sized according to information available only at run time, then either dynamic memory allocation or a [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530363/whats-the-point-of-vla-anyway) can be used.  First, for dynamic memory, instead of defining with array notation, create a pointer instance:

```
... } *prsn;
```

Then, in a function, use `calloc` or `malloc` to create memory for say 1000 instances:

```
int someFunction(void)
{
    prsn = calloc(1000, sizeof(struct Person));
    if(prsn)
    {
        // Use instances of prsn
        // free when finished
        free(prsn);
    }
```

For VLA the instances created must have local scope.  So, inside a function somewhere, do this:

```
int someFunction(int sizeOfStruct)
{
    struct Person newPerson[sizeOfStruct] = {0};
```

Note this method does not require freeing memory associated with `newPerson`

Comment: Though for an unlimited number of Persons, the OP might do better to use a linked list, or perhaps an array of pointers to Person, especially if the number of Persons might change during runtime.  Otherwise you'll spend a lot of time copying the existing members, either manually or by a calll to realloc.

Answer (score 9):

The two pieces of code above are equivalent.

In the first one, you define `struct Person` and define `prsn` as an array of 20 elements of that struct at the same time.  In the second, you first define the struct then separately define the array.

In C, array indexes start at 0, so in both cases the `prsn` array contains elements indexed from 0 to 19.  This does *not* affect the size of the `name` member, which is a 50 element array.  You have an array of 20 `struct Person`, each of which contains a 50 element array of `char` called `name`.

Regarding making the array size unlimited, an array **must** have a size, either specified explicitly between `[` and `]` or implicitly via an initializer list. The size can be a variable however such an array cannot be defined at file scope, and the size variable must have been assigned a value previously.

Comment: So that means an array of prsn[0] to prsn[19] right ? And what i have to do if i want to make the elements unlimited ? prsn[n] or prsn[] or just prsn ?

Comment: @abw1904 An array *must* have a size, either specified explicitly between `[` and `]` or implicitly via an initializer list.  The size can be a variable however such an array cannot be defined at file scope, and the size variable must have been assigned a value previously.

Comment: @abw1904 To code a "variable size array" you should take a look at Linked-List. Obviously will be not unlimited, but it can grow at runtime

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an Array of 20 struct of that type