# Expression must have a constant value in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
int LCS_length(char* x, char* y)
{
    int m = strlen(x);
    int n = strlen(y);

    char b[m + 1][n + 1];
    char c[m + 1][n + 1];
}
```

In this code i want to declare a new two dimensional arrays, but my compiler write me this error:

**Expression must have a constant value**

Who knows what can i do, because a compiler don't let me do this statement in C language?

**NOTE**: it just part of the code and it has return statement later.

Comment: You need to return something

Comment: If you are using GCC/ICC/Clang, make sure to compile with `-std=c99` or higher

Comment: That is because the particular compiler does not support Variable Length Arrays (e.g. MS VC). You either need to use constant values that will *always* be large enough, or use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: read at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Comment: Your C compiler does not support variable length arrays. I suppose you use Visual Studio?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes

Comment: @maylor You could also configure Visual Studio to use GCC or Clang as compiler, to compile C code.

Comment: @isrnick how can i do it? it would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must compile the code with a standard C compiler, such as gcc or clang etc. You can't compile using C++ compilers or non-C-compilers such as Microsoft VS.

Other than that, the code is fine apart from missing a `return` statement.

If you are stuck with old crap compilers, you can alternatively do an old style "mangled array":

```
size_t m = strlen(something) + 1;
size_t n = strlen(something) + 1;
...
char* b = malloc(m*n);
...
b[i*n + j] = something;
...
free(b);
```

That is how we used to allocate 2D arrays dynamically back in the old days.

Equivalent code using dynamic allocation in modern standard C would be:

```
char (*b)[n] = malloc( sizeof(char[m][n]));
...
b[i][j] = something;
...
free(b);
```

Comment: I wrote here only part of the code that did not work

Comment: i have Return statement later

Comment: is the equivalent code using dynamic allocation in modern standard C faster?

Comment: @maylor No, any decent compiler will give the very same machine code for both snippets. See the machine code from gcc for example: https://godbolt.org/z/q70JYc. Some `char**` version will be significantly slower though.

Comment: How do you get from (m+1)(n+1) elements in `char b[m + 1][n + 1];` to `sizeof(char[m][n]) + 1`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was simplifying things a bit because `b[i*(n+1) + j]` is some severely ugly code. Hmm hang on, there's a better way yet. Edited.

Comment: The original code seeks to allocate (m+1)(n+1) elements. (The question does not show what it intends to do with them. Perhaps it is a mistake. But it is what it is.) Allocating space for `sizeof(char [m][n])` does not make space for the same number of elements. If the code truly is doing something with (m+1)(n+1) elements, then this allocation is insufficient. (The name, `LCS_length`, suggests [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) but still does not clue us in about their code.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that it wants a specific constant value like: `char b[5][5];`

Comment: A return statement is missing also

Answer (score 0):

> Expression must have a constant value

C supports variable sized arrays from C99 standard. Maybe your  compiler does not support Variable Length Arrays.

You can see more information at [What's the point of VLA anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530363/whats-the-point-of-vla-anyway).

And may be helpful: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

You can use dynamically allocation instead (Unless you want each index to be a variable-length string, there is really no need for the `char**` trick: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)):

```
char **b = malloc((m+1)*sizeof(char *));
if(b) {
   for (int i = 0; i < m+1; i++0 {
      b[i] = malloc(n+1);
      if(!b[i]) {
         // handle the error.
      }
   }
}
```

Or you can define the constant value `MAX_ROW_LENGTH` and `MAX_COL_LENGTH`:

```
#define MAX_ROW_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_COL_LENGTH 256
```

Then you can use:

```
char b[MAX_ROW_LENGTH][MAX_COL_LENGTH];
```

Comment: Unless the OP wants each index to be a variable-length string, there is really no need for the `char**` trick. It seems they want actual 2D arrays, so they shouldn't be using some `char**` heap fragmentation fiasco then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: i got it. Can i add your link to the answer ?

Comment: You can, but we really shouldn't teach people to use this method unless they actually need it. Like when allocating a 1D array of pointers to strings of individual lengths.