# The pointer access representation of the program

Tags: c, pointers

The code ran differently than I predicted, I think `*(score+i*n+j)` is problematic, it could also be a problem elsewhere, I'm not quite sure, but I don't know how to modify it.

```
#include  <stdio.h>

#define STUD 30            // Maximum number of students possible
#define COURSE 5           // The maximum number of possible exam subjects

void  Total(int *score, int sum[], float aver[], int m, int n);
void  Print(int *score, int sum[], float aver[], int m, int n);

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, m, n, score[STUD][COURSE], sum[STUD];
    float aver[STUD];
    printf("Enter the total number of students and courses:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    printf("Enter score:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &score[i][j]);
        }
    }

    Total(*score, sum, aver, m, n);
    Print(*score, sum, aver, m, n);
    return 0;
}

void  Total(int *score, int sum[], float aver[], int m, int n)
{
    int  i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            sum[i] = sum[i] + *(score + i * n + j);
        }

        aver[i] = (float) sum[i] / n;
    }
}

void  Print(int *score, int sum[], float aver[], int m, int n)
{
    int  i, j;
    printf("Result:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%4d\t", *(score + i * n + j));
        }

        printf("%5d\t%6.1f\n", sum[i], aver[i]);
    }
}
```

Example of a program running:

```
Enter the total number of students and courses:
2 3↙
Enter score:
90↙
95↙
97↙
82↙
73↙
69↙
Result:
  90  95  97  282  94.0
  82  73  69  224  74.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling your program yields no warnings or errors. Running it with the sample input you've provided yields:

```
Enter the total number of students and courses:
2 3
Enter score:
90
95
97
82
73
69
Result:
  90      95      97      282     94.0
404780     0      82    404862  134954.0
```

This is correct for the first set of scores, but not the second. As you intuited, this means your math for accessing the array via pointer math is probably wrong.

Consider what your array actually looks like in memory. You've allocated on the stack an array that looks like:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Your example input has filled it like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 90| 95| 97|   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 82| 73| 69|   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
...
```

If you want to access the first element of the second row, you need your offset to be `i * 5` rather than `i * 3` which is what happens when you use `i * n`. This `5` we can get from your constant `COURSE`.

```
*(score + i * COURSE + j)
```

When you use a different offset you get data which has not been initialized, which is why you see garbage values. If you initialize all of the values in your array to `0`, but leave your code otherwise unchanged, you can see this in action.

```
int i, j, m, n, score[STUD][COURSE] = {0}, sum[STUD];
```

```
Enter the total number of students and courses:
2 3
Enter score:
90
95
97
82
73
69
Result:
  90      95      97      282     94.0
   0       0      82       82     27.3
```

Comment: Accessing an array this way is actually UB.

Answer (score 2):

As you note, the problem is your array accesses -- you use `score[i][j]` in main to fill the array and then `*(score + i * n + j)` in your `Total` and `Print` functions to try to access it, and these are different and incompatible.  The easiest fix is probably just to fix the declarations of `Total` and `Print` to match the `score` you are using:

```
void  Total(int score[][COURSE], int sum[], float aver[], int m, int n);
void  Print(int score[][COURSE], int sum[], float aver[], int m, int n);
```

Then you can just use `score[i][j]` in them and everything should work.  You would also pass `score` as just `score` instead of `*score`.

Alternately, change the declaration of `score` to `score[STUD*COURSE]` and use
 `*(score + i * n + j)` (or `score[i*n + j]`) in main to access it like you do in `Total` and `Print`.

Answer (score 0):

OP is unclear why the code uses `#defines` to define values for rows and columns of the array *`score`*, then goes on to use `scanf()` to enter new values that may or may not conflict with the `#defines`, or even overflow the array memory.   Either method works, but using both together confuse things.  Pick one or the other.

Aside: If a dynamic sized array is necessary, then it can be created as a pointer, or pointers to allocated memory, or by use of a [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530363/whats-the-point-of-vla-anyway)

eg:  A short example of using user input with dynamic memory allocation to create the array sized to the need of the moment:

Note: following method allows you to use plain array notation to assign values:

```
score[i][j] = someValue://easy to use and readable
//as opposed to 
*(score + i*n + j) = someValue;// cumbersome to use and read
```

Example:

```
int student, course;//using descriptive variables
printf("Enter the total number of students and courses:\n");
scanf("%d %d",&student,&course);
int (*score)[course] = create_arr_2d (student, course);
if(score)
{   //use score
    ...
    free(score);
}
```

Where `create_arr_2d(...)` is defined:

```
void * create_arr_2d (size_t x, size_t y)
{
    int (*ptr_2)[x] = malloc( sizeof (int *[y]) ); //allocate a true 2D array    
    if(ptr_2)
    {
        memset(ptr_2, 0, sizeof **ptr_2);
    }
    return ptr_2;
}
```

([credit for method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays/42094467#42094467))

Addressing your code as is.  First, the following creates variables, but does not initialize any of them:

```
int i, j, m, n, score[STUD][COURSE], sum[STUD];
float aver[STUD];
```

To eliminate some of the issues you may be seeing, initialize:

```
int i=0, j=0, m=0, n=0, score[STUD][COURSE]={{0}}, sum[STUD]={0};
float aver[STUD]={0};
```

In the function prototype in your given code:

```
Total(int *score, int sum[], float aver[], int m, int n)
```

`int *score`

suggests a pointer to a single dimensional array is being passed, but if it is being used to represent `score[STUD][COURSE]`, then it should be passed as `score[m][n], with the prototype changed as:

```
Total(int m, int n, int score[m][n], int sum[m], float aver[m]);
```

Then called as:

```
Total(STUD, COURSE, score[STUD][COURSE], sum[STUD], aver[STUD]){...}
```

Note, this arrangement makes use of [VLA type function arguemnts](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/vla-as-function-arguments/)

Note also, an array such as:  (shortened from your values for easier viewing)

```
int m = 5;
int n = 4
int array[m][n] = {{0}}
```

creates a single contiguous block of memory, conceivably looking like this in memory:

```
`|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|...`
 0         5        10         15       20
```

Where all of the elements can be accessed in a for loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<m; i++
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       *(array + i*n + j);
   ...
...
```