# Passing two-dimensional array with including sizes to function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I want to pass a two-dimensional array to a function, however, I want to do that with *arbitrary* size.

First, please have a look to following code:

```
#define MAX_ROWS 8
#define MAX_SIZE 32

static void foo(char array[][MAX_SIZE], size_t max_rows, size_t max_size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_rows; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char array[MAX_ROWS][MAX_SIZE];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        snprintf(array[i], MAX_SIZE, "Row: %d", i);
    }
    
    foo(array, MAX_ROWS, MAX_SIZE);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**A.** This code works as expected. But there is one line I don't like:

```
static void foo(char array[][MAX_SIZE], size_t max_rows, size_t max_size)
```

I don't like it because not only I need to specify the maximum size two times, I need to hardcode the maximum size for the 2nd dimension to make it available during compile time.

**B.** An alternative approach would be making an variable length array (VLA). For that we would need to change the order of the parameters so the `size_t max_size` appears before the array:

```
static void foo(size_t max_rows, size_t max_size, char array[][max_size])
foo(MAX_ROWS, MAX_SIZE, array);
```

I like this solution on one hand, but I don't like it on the other hand. It is part of the C99 standard but not supported by MSVC. Therefore, I simply can't use it.

Also I am not sure if this kind of use would be discouraged due to security reasons, even if the size is - due to the use of the macro constants - still *de facto* hardcoded and therefore actually not variable.

**C.** From what I understand, `char array[MAX_ROWS][MAX_SIZE]` is internally nothing more then a buffer with a size of `max_rows * max_size * sizeof(char)`. So I was thinking about following solution, but this results in a `Segmentation Fault`:

```
static void foo(void *array0, size_t max_rows, size_t max_size) {
    size_t total_size = max_rows * max_size * sizeof(char);
    
    char *array = malloc(total_size);
    memcpy(array, array0, total_size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_rows; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    free(array);
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n", array[i]);` you can't  print a `char` with `%s`

Comment: I want to print the sequence of characters until `\0` termination. In both variant A and B it works. You're right that the error occurs at `printf`, but that is not the real reason as I don't want to only print one character.

Comment: Sometimes you can replace a VLA with a flexible array member. Have you considered using a real C compiler (MinGW or clang) on Windows?

Comment: Well, I only do C, so that might be a thing to think about, but I've not yet researched enough about that because I primarily do C only for Windows based programs whereas I use other languages on Linux. I will have a look to flexible array members.

Comment: "not supported by MSVC" I strongly suggest to get yourself *a C compiler* (clang/gcc/tcc/even Intel's icc). Don't use this crapware from microsoft which is actually a C++ compiler with some features disables.

Comment: Hmm, but isn't it anyway the case that VLAs (which I would like to use here) are discouraged or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: @Tintenfisch, VLA **objects** are discouraged, but VLA **types** are very encouraged. They are mandatory again in upcoming C23. Read the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163435/4989451) describing common misconceptions of VLAs and how they should be used properly.

Comment: @tstanisl Thanks for that clarification. I will try to move to another compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointer arithmetic over a `char *`, this is how functions like [qsort](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/qsort.c) do it when they don't know the concrete type of the passed array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void foo(void *array0, size_t max_rows, size_t max_size)
{
    const char *ptr = array0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_rows; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr += max_size;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum {MAX_ROWS = 3, MAX_SIZE = 4};
    char array[MAX_ROWS][MAX_SIZE] = {"abc", "cde", "fgh"};

    foo(array, MAX_ROWS, MAX_SIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abc
cde
fgh
```

Quote from the [C-FAQ](https://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc2.html):

> It must be noted, however, that a program which performs
> multidimensional array subscripting ``by hand'' in this way is not in
> strict conformance with the ANSI C Standard; according to an official
> interpretation, the behavior of accessing (&array[0][0])[x] is not
> defined for x >= NCOLUMNS.

Therefore, this answer (and the other answer provided by [@0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77073983/1606345) using row-major order) are not strictly conforming with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Notes:

- `C` has no multi-dimensional arrays like `FORTRAN`. Just arrays.
- array is a name for an address and has a size, like in `int array[40]`.

  - the name of the array points to its address.
  - the size is the product of the number of elements by the size of each one
- but `C` can have arrays of anything, so an array can be an array of arrays, an array of arrays of arrays, and so on.
- array elements are allocated in memory line after line, from left.

### EXAMPLE

Consider this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    union
    {
        char i3D[2][2][2];
        char i1D[8];
    } view = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    printf(
        "size of `char i3D[2][2][2]` is %u\n",
        sizeof(view.i3D));
    printf(
        "size of `char[2][2][2]` is %u\n",
        sizeof(char[2][2][2]));
    printf("size of `char` is %u\n", sizeof(char));

    printf(
        "first element is %d at 0x%p, last is %d at 0x%p\n",
        view.i3D[0][0][0], &view.i3D[0][0][0], view.i3D[1][1][1],
        &view.i3D[1][1][1]);
    char offset = &view.i3D[1][1][1] - &view.i3D[0][0][0];
    printf(
        "offset of the last element from the start is %d * "
        "sizeof(char) = %d\n",
        offset, offset * sizeof(view.i3D[0][0][0]));

    return 0;
}
```

That shows in a test run

```
size of `char i3D[2][2][2]` is 8
size of `char[2][2][2]` is 8
size of `char` is 1
first element is 0 at 0x012FFD44, last is 7 at 0x012FFD4B
offset of the last element from the start is 7 * sizeof(char) = 7
```

If we inspect memory at this address

```
0x012FFD40  cc cc cc cc 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  ÌÌÌÌ........
0x012FFD4C  cc cc cc cc 87 56 cb 02 74 fd 2f 01  ÌÌÌÌ.VË.tý/.
0x012FFD58  63 22 da 00 01 00 00 00 f0 5c 62 01  c"Ú.....ð\b.
0x012FFD64  08 63 62 01 01 00 00 00 f0 5c 62 01  .cb.....ð\b.
0x012FFD70  08 63 62 01 d0 fd 2f 01 b7 20 da 00  .cb.Ðý/.· Ú.
```

we see the array data at the expected address at runtime

### Back to the original code

The code are trying to pass an array of strings to a `foo()` function.

As an example, this is the common prototype of `main`, for every `C` program:

```
    int main (int argc, char** argv)
```

And it does the same thing. And works, ever. The types are different, since `foo()` is declaring

```
    static void foo(char array[][MAX_SIZE], size_t max_rows, size_t max_size)
```

But inside `foo()` the rows are only accessed by a call to `printf()` as

```
     for (size_t i = 0; i < max_rows; i++)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
```

And `%s` is for a null-terminated string, so `char_array` in `foo()` is very much like `argv` in every `C` program

#### From a `char block[10][20]` to  a `char** line`

In `block` we have a continuous block of data with 200 bytes. `line` is a single pointer.

- `block[0]` is `char[20]` and can have a string of up to 19 `char` plus the terminating `NULL`.
- from `block[0]` to `block[9]` we can have 10 of these strings.
- `line` can also be seen as an array. It is `C` *array to pointer decay* thing.
- `*line` is `char*`. It is the result of the `*` operator.
- `line[0]` is the same as `*line`. It is `C` *pointer arithmetic: `line[0]` = `*(line + 0)`.
- `**line` is a single `char`. The first letter of the first string, like `block[0][0]` in `block`

#### But how do we know how many rows and lines are in `block`? And how many pointers in `line`?

**We do not**. We need to keep the dimensions saved elsewhere, or we count: this is why we need `strlen()` to compute a string size anytime we need. Something similar can for sure be used for `line` here, using a `NULL` pointer at the end of `line`

This is the reason for `argc` in `main`: keep count of the number of pointers in the `argv` array

### Encapsulation and an example

I will write an example using this idea of encapsulation, enclosing the data in a `struct` and writing a minimum of functions to manipulate it.

#### Using `char**`

Just as the system builds one for `main` we will create the `argv` array in `line`:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        size_t incr;   // increment size
        size_t limit;  // actual allocated size
        size_t size;   // size in use
        char** line;   // the lines
    } Block;
```

Each block is created empty, with a size = `limit`. If needed a resize is made in terms of a set of `incr` pointers. The reason for this: reallocate memory can be expensive in terms of time, since the whole array may need to be copied.

#### functions for `Block`

```
Block* create_blk(size_t size, size_t increment);
Block* delete_blk(Block* block_to_go);
int    resize_blk(Block* block_to_go);
int    show_blk(Block* block, const char* msg);
```

The mininum for testing. Function names are self explanatory.

- `show_blk()` accepts an opional message
- `resize()` is implemented only for expansion. Reduce size is rivial if needed

**A possible implementation an example of use is at the end of this post**

#### function helpers for testing

```
        Block* load_file(const char* file);
```

This function just loads a file into a new `Block` and returns the `Block` address. Easy way of testing the functions.

#### `main()` for a test

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char msg[80] = {0};
    if (argc < 2) usage();
    Block* test = load_file(argv[1]);
    if (test == NULL) return -1;
    sprintf(
        msg, "\n\n==> Loading \"%s\" into memory", argv[1]);
    show_blk(test, msg);
    qsort(test->line, test->size, sizeof(void*), cmp_line);
    sprintf(msg, "\n\n==> \"%s\" after sort in-memory", argv[1]);
    show_blk(test, msg);
    test = delete_blk(test);
    return 0;
};
```

This program expects a file name on the command line. Then

- creates a `Block` with all lines in file
- shows the contents of the struct as it is in memory
- calls `qsort()` to sort all lines inside the block
- shows the lines ordered, inside the `struct`
- deletes everything

#### output for `p.exe stuff.h`

Here is the output of a test using the file `stuff.h`

```
loading "stuff.h" into memory
Block extended for a total of 20 pointers


==> Loading "stuff.h" into memory
Status: 18 of 20 lines. [Incr. is 16]:
   1    #pragma once
   2    #include <stdio.h>
   3    #include <stdlib.h>
   4    #include <string.h>
   5
   6    typedef struct
   7    {
   8        size_t incr;   // increment size
   9        size_t limit;  // actual allocated size
  10        size_t size;   // size in use
  11        char** line;   // the lines
  12
  13    } Block;
  14
  15    Block* create_blk(size_t size, size_t increment);
  16    Block* delete_blk(Block* block_to_go);
  17    int    resize_blk(Block* block_to_go);
  18    int    show_blk(Block* block, const char* msg);


==> "stuff.h" after sort in-memory
Status: 18 of 20 lines. [Incr. is 16]:
   1
   2
   3
   4        char** line;   // the lines
   5        size_t incr;   // increment size
   6        size_t limit;  // actual allocated size
   7        size_t size;   // size in use
   8    #include <stdio.h>
   9    #include <stdlib.h>
  10    #include <string.h>
  11    #pragma once
  12    Block* create_blk(size_t size, size_t increment);
  13    Block* delete_blk(Block* block_to_go);
  14    int    resize_blk(Block* block_to_go);
  15    int    show_blk(Block* block, const char* msg);
  16    typedef struct
  17    {
  18    } Block;
```

### Complete code for `stuff.h stuff.c main.c` [this test]

#### `stuff.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t incr;   // increment size
    size_t limit;  // actual allocated size
    size_t size;   // size in use
    char** line;   // the lines

} Block;

Block* create_blk(size_t size, size_t increment);
Block* delete_blk(Block* block_to_go);
int    resize_blk(Block* block_to_go);
int    show_blk(Block* block, const char* msg);
```

#### `stuff.c`

```
#include "stuff.h"

Block* create_blk(size_t size, size_t increment)
{
    Block* nb = (Block*)malloc(sizeof(Block));
    if (nb == NULL) return NULL;
    nb->incr  = increment;
    nb->limit = size;
    nb->size  = 0;
    nb->line  = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    return nb;
}

Block* delete_blk(Block* blk)
{
    if (blk == NULL) return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < blk->size; i += 1)
        free(blk->line[i]);  // free lines
    free(blk->line);         // free block
    free(blk);               // free struct
    return NULL;
}

int resize_blk(Block* nb)
{
    const size_t new_sz = nb->limit + nb->incr;
    char*        new_block =
        realloc(nb->line, (new_sz * sizeof(char*)));
    if (new_block == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "\tCould not extend block to %zd "
            "lines\n",
            new_sz);
        return -1;
    }
    nb->limit = new_sz;
    nb->line  = (char**)new_block;
    return 0;
}   // resize_blk()
 
int show_blk(Block* bl, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    if (bl == NULL)
    {
        printf("Status: not allocated\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(
        "Status: %zd of %zd lines. [Incr. is %zd]:\n",
        bl->size, bl->limit, bl->incr);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < bl->size; i += 1)
        printf("%4d\t%s", 1 + i, bl->line[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

#### `main.c`

```
#include "stuff.h"

int    cmp_line(const void*, const void*);
Block* load_file(const char*);
void   usage();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char msg[80] = {0};
    if (argc < 2) usage();
    Block* test = load_file(argv[1]);
    if (test == NULL) return -1;
    sprintf(
        msg, "\n\n==> Loading \"%s\" into memory", argv[1]);
    show_blk(test, msg);
    qsort(test->line, test->size, sizeof(void*), cmp_line);
    sprintf(msg, "\n\n==> \"%s\" after sort in-memory", argv[1]);
    show_blk(test, msg);
    test = delete_blk(test);
    return 0;
};

int cmp_line(const void* one, const void* other)
{
    return strcmp(
        *((const char**)one), *((const char**)other));
}

Block* load_file(const char* f_name)
{
    if (f_name == NULL) return NULL;
    fprintf(stderr, "loading \"%s\" into memory\n", f_name);
    FILE* F = fopen(f_name, "r");
    if (F == NULL) return NULL;
    // file is open
    Block* nb = create_blk(4, 16);  // block size is 8
    char   line[200];
    char*  p = &line[0];
    p        = fgets(p, sizeof(line), F);
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        // is block full?
        if (nb->size >= nb->limit)
        {
            resize_blk(nb);
            printf(
                "Block extended for a total of %zd "
                "pointers\n",
                nb->limit);
        }
        // now copy the line
        nb->line[nb->size] = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(p));
        strcpy(nb->line[nb->size], p);
        nb->size += 1;
        // read next line
        p = fgets(p, sizeof(line), F);
    };  // while()
    fclose(F);
    return nb;
}

void usage()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Use: program file_to_load\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Not really tested, but it shows a way of writing this kind of stuff. As the code is in the `stuff.c` file it can be used in minutes in any program. Just include `stuff.h`.

Comment: This is very helpful to learn. Which is the reason I've chosen to first learn C and then C++ because I want to understand C very deeply.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go in my case - as recommended by @tstanisl - was to change the compiler in order to make use of a VLA, to be precise: In order to use a **VMT**, a variably-modified type. Not only is this anyway part of the C99 standard, it is mandatory in the upcoming C23 (see [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2778.pdf)), so I was wrong thinking it was discouraged.

In my case I changed the compiler to Clang. Clang support in MSVC can be installed in

`New Project > Installed > Templates > Visual C++ > Cross Platform`

and then be enabled in

`Project Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Platform Toolset`.

Comment: Well, SO is not a place for opinion, but I would add that changing the compiler to use an obscure feature is almost never possible. VLA is great for students that struggle to grasp the need to know an array size at compile time. The way to go in any OO language is to encapsulate your data and size info as an object and build the code around this object. Is ok in `C`, Assembler. `C++`. You call a thing and get a pointer to some bytes. You call other thing and free this bytes.

Comment: Isn't the VLA (better said the VMT), which is C99 standard, not simply the better solution here? Because the size is de-facto static, so known at compiler time, it is only about to pass it through the function (I currently only use C to not mix C and C++).

Comment: I see your point, but at the first line of your post: _I want to pass a two-dimensional array to a function, however, I want to do that with arbitrary size._ It is arbitrary or is it known at compile time? In general we write code as generic as possible. That is one reason for encapsulation. And note that VLA can work around X[N] but will not give you the value of N. It can be or end up in the standard, but it will go anywhere but students code. A framework will not return you a VLA or VLT, a network driver also will not. We will see

Comment: And who would want a variable sized thing in the stack? And if it goes on the heap *o*r in the stack? Who would rely on such a thing? And if it goes always in the heap then goes away the possible speed gain and comes in a simple allocation.

Comment: 'arbitrary' was indeed the wrong term here or at least misleading, because more important here is that the size is known at compiler time, so I changed the headline accordingly to my code example. You say a VLA will not give me the value of N. I don't understand. What exactly is the problem with a VMT? Please have a look to the example in the proposal of C23: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2778.pdf

Comment: Look at the (single) 4-line example in the proposal you listed... `n` is passed along as an argument. In your `foo` case it would be 2 arguments.

Comment: `foo(int n, double (*x)[n])` and `foo(int n, int m, double (*x)[n][m])` or even `foo(int n, int m, double (*x)[][n][m])` should be in all cases an example for valid VMT use (?)

Comment: Yes, I believe all of them are. And as I told you, and as I wrote in the example, write just `foo(Block* block)` and encapsulate all your data in `Block` definition as you see fit.

Comment: But why is your example better than the very simple VMT? I don't understand that yet.

Comment: It is not just _my example_. Did you read the code I wrote? It is a single parameter. It is independent. You can implement anything as `x`. Why in any world would be better *not* to encapsulate the _metadata`? Just look at our 2 previous comments.

Answer (score -1):

```
void foo(void *array, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    char *arr = array;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr + i * cols);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char array[10][100];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); i++) {
        snprintf(array[i], sizeof(array[0]) / sizeof(array[0][0]), "Row: %d", i);
    }
    
    foo(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), sizeof(array[0]) / sizeof(array[0][0]));
    
    return 0;
}
```