# gcc errors while working in a variable-length pointer array in C

Tags: c

I'm getting this error:

> list.c list.h types.h
>   list.c: In function 'List_push':
>   list.c:11:23: error: invalid initializer
>   --- void *values[len] = ls->values);

**EDIT**:

Now, with my current code (I've done undos/redos that removed somethings), I get this error instead:

[image: gcc]

Why?

Basically I've a `List` structure which declares an variable-length array, containing void pointers (what I want is pointers to any data type). You can see it below at the list.h file.

I've tried a mix of changes in list.c (i.e., `*values[pos++] = ...`, etc...), but doing these changes it only results in worse gcc errors.

**wscom.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"
#include "types.h"

int main() {
    List ls;
    // TEST: Put a value pointer at index 0
    uint8 value = 0x41;
    List_push(&ls, 1, &value);
    printf("%c",
        *(char*) List_getindex(&ls, 0)
    );
    return 0;
}
```

**types.h**

```
#ifndef hydroTrackerTypesH
#define hydroTrackerTypesH

typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned long long uint32;

#endif
```

**list.h** (Declarations)

```
#ifndef hydroTrackerListH
#define hydroTrackerListH

#include "types.h"

typedef struct {
    uint32 length;
    void *values[];
} List;

void  List_push(List *ls, uint8 count, ...);
void *List_getindex(List *ls, uint32 i);
void  List_setindex(List *ls, uint32 i, void *v);

#endif
```

**list.c** (Defns.)

```
#include "list.h"
#include "types.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static size_t PointerSize =
    sizeof(void*);

void List_push(List *ls, uint8 count, ...) {
    uint32 len = ls->length;
    void *values[len] = ls->values;
    uint32 sum = len + count;
    realloc(&values, sum * PointerSize);
    ls->length = sum;

    va_list newVals;
    va_start(newVals, count);
    uint8 pos = len;

    while(count--)
        values[pos++] = va_arg(newVals, void*);

    va_end(newVals);
}

void *List_getindex(List *ls, uint32 i) {
    return (void *)(ls->values[i]);
}

//void List_setindex(List *ls, uint32 i, void *v);
```

Comment: `void *values[0]` declares an array of `0` elements. What would you think that the compiler should do with this?

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, I've a made an undo/redo mistaken in my code. It was supposed to be `void *values[len]`, for example.

Comment: If I understand your code right you have to use `void **values;` instead of `void *values[0]`. `void **values;` has to be read as a pointer to a void pointer (or multiple of them). This is meant for the `struct List` as well as in the function `List_push()`. You may use `values` like an array of `void*` (e.g. with subscript operator `[]`). This is a C specialty unknown in other languages like Javascript or Pascal...

Comment: "It was supposed to be void *values[len], for example" What is `len`? Is it known at the point of declaration of `values`? Is it a constant expression? If not, you cannot have `void *values[len]`, you need `void**  values`. In other news, (1) your `List_push` interface is dangerous, requiring the second argument and the number of pointers to be in sync; and (2) `List` isn't going to initialize itself, you need to explicitly set up an empty list, and you want a dedicated function to do just that.

Comment: @Scheff So that's like declaring nested pointers, right? Unfortunately I got compilation errors in different ways of using this pointer :/

Comment: @n.m. I've updated the question. This `len` is just `List#length`, which I won't change in other parts of the code (I'll use it safely). I've tried this special `**` pointer way as suggested by Scheff, but I still got compilation errors on its usage.  I thought `List` would be `0` at all. I thought on creating an initializer function too before (but I'm not sure this affects the compilation errors).

Comment: `List#length` is not C. Try to express what you want in C. "I'll use it safely". Irrelevant. Array size must be known at array *declaration* time, and it must be a compile-time constant in most cases (including yours). None of the above holds, so the code is invalid, end of story. "but I still got compilation errors" This doesn't give you a license to use `values[len]`. You need to use `void ** values`, if you have problems using it, ask a question.

Comment: @n.m. I got it, then `typedef struct { void *values[0]; } List;` is not what I want, right? There's no way because `typedef struct { void *values[]; } List;` causes a syntax error. Anyways, out of this, I don't know how to use the variable of `void ** values` approach :v. It compiles without errs, but when I do `if ((*(uint8*)List_getindex(&ls, 0)) == 0x41) printf("Wow");` in main code, it doesn't print (`List_getindex(&ls, 0)` should return the value from `uint8 value = 0x41;`).

Comment: `void *values[0];` declares a zero length array, which is not legal in C. `void *values[];` declares a *flexible member* which your compiler doesn't support and which you don't want to use anyway. "I don't know how to use the variable of `void ** values` approach" That's a problem you need to solve. It looks like you know about `realloc`. If you have written a working program with `realloc` once, it contains everything you need to find your way through this problem. If not, perhaps you should step back and do some more basic exercises.

Comment: @n.m. It looks like my compiler does support this flexible member feature, but it somehow didn't let me use it before. Thanks for the motivation

Comment: Don't use the flexible member feature. You don't want to, it's more complicated that you are prepared to tackle.

Comment: Use `#include <stdint.h>` instead of your `types.h`, it will be much less confusing for everybody reading your code

Comment: @M.M I remind I've used some of these `uint8_t` and such types, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: [you should copy the error output text and paste here instead of capturing and post as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit long for a comment.
Thus, I make it an answer.

I try to show you how pointers and arrays are related to each other:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  /* The compiler allocates space for "Hello" and '\0' (5 + 1 chars)
   * and stores the address in aString1.
   */
  const char *aString1 = "Hello";
  /* The compiler allocates 10 chars and initializes
   * it with "World" (and the '\0' for terminator).
   */
  const char aString2[10] = "World";
  /* The compiler determines length of initializer "I'm here."
   * (9 + 1) and allocates the array of appropriate size.
   */
  const char aString3[] = "I'm here.";
  /* allocate storage for array (3 const char*) */
#if 0 /* the usual way */
  const char **array = malloc(3 * sizeof (const char*));
#else /* how Matheus wants to do it */
  const char **array = NULL;
  array = realloc(array, 3 * sizeof (const char*));
#endif /* 0 */
  /* assign contents (using it like an array) */
  array[0] = aString1;
  array[1] = aString2;
  array[2] = aString3;
  /* apply array to another variable array2 */
  const char **array2 = array; /* assigns the address only */
  /* use it: */
  printf("array2[0]: '%s', array2[1]: '%s', array2[2]: '%s'\n",
    array2[0], array2[1], array2[2]);
  /* throw away storage of array (and array2) */
  free(array);
  /* Attention! array, array2 become wild pointers at this point
   * and may not be accessed (except new, valid addresses are assigned).
   * However, aString1, aString2, aString3 are still intact.
   */
  printf("aString1: '%s', aString2: '%s', aString3: '%s'\n",
    aString1, aString2, aString3);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

The sample can be tested on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4JYGH7).

The sample output is:

```
array2[0]: 'Hello', array2[1]: 'World', array2[2]: 'I'm here.'
aString1: 'Hello', aString2: 'World', aString3: 'I'm here.'
```

**Update:**

So, I finally looked again on to the question & answer of [Matheus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5066707/matheus) and tried to fix it according to his intention (or how I understood it). I based it on [Matheus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5066707/matheus)' implementation and remarked modified codes by comments:

`list.h`:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#if 0 /* not necessary to define these types */
#include "types.h"
#else /* they are already available in a (better) portable manner: */
#include <stdint.h>
/* Btw. I had to change:
 * uint8 -> uint8_t
 * uint32 -> uint32_t
 */
#endif /* 0 */

typedef struct {
  uint32_t length;
#if 0 /* gcc ERROR: */
  /* list.c:17:3: error: invalid use of flexible array member
   * ls->values = NULL;
   */
  void *values[];
#else /* (not) 0 */
  void **values;
#endif /* 0 */
} List;

void  List_init(List *ls);
void  List_push(List *ls, uint8_t count, ...);
void* List_getindex(List *ls, uint32_t i);
void  List_setindex(List *ls, uint32_t i, void *v);

#endif /* LIST_H */
```

`list.c`:

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if 0 /* no need for a variable (with storage */
static size_t PointerSize = sizeof(void*);
#else /* use enum instead (constant) */
enum { PointerSize = sizeof(void*) };
#endif /* 0 */

void List_init(List *ls)
{
  ls->length = 0;
  /* This is important: */
  ls->values = NULL;
  /* or 1st realloc() in List_push() may have Undefined Behavior.) */
}

void List_push(List *ls, uint8_t count, ...)
{
  uint32_t len = ls->length;
  uint32_t sum = len + count;
  void **values = realloc(ls->values, sum * PointerSize);
  if (!values) {
    /* realloc() failed! Bail out before destroying the existing data. */
    return;
  }
  ls->length = sum;
  ls->values = values;
  /* assign new contents */
  va_list newVals;
  va_start(newVals, count);
#if 1 /* the readable way: */
  int pos = len;
  while (count--) values[pos++] = va_arg(newVals, void*);
#else /* the hackish C style way: */
  values += len;
  while (count--) *values++ = va_arg(newVals, void*);
#endif /* 1 */
  va_end(newVals);
}

void* List_getindex(List *ls, uint32_t i)
{
  return ls->values[i];
}
```

`wscom.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
  List ls;
  /* Put a value pointers at indices 0, 1, 2 */
  uint8_t value1 = 0x41, value2 = 0x42;
  uint8_t value3[3] = { 0x43, 0x44, 0x45 };
  List_init(&ls);
  List_push(&ls, 3, &value1, &value2, value3);
  /* Check whether list contents can be retrieved again */
  if ((*(uint8_t*)List_getindex(&ls, 0)) == 0x41) {
    printf("List entry 0 is correct.\n");
  }
  if ((*(uint8_t*)List_getindex(&ls, 1)) == 0x42) {
    printf("List entry 1 is correct.\n");
  }
  { uint8_t *values = List_getindex(&ls, 2);
    if (values[0] == 0x43
      && values[1] == 0x44
      && values[2] == 0x45) {
      printf("List entry 2 is correct.\n");
    }
  }
  /* Done. */
  return 0;
}
```

In one of my comments, I stated that `void *values[];` in `struct List` might be OK. Ahem, I was wrong. gcc remarks this as error when I tried to use it in `list.c`. So, actually, it is OK but not for what I intend it to use.

Finally, my sample session (using gcc in cygwin on Windows 10):

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o wscom wscom.c list.c

$ ./wscom
List entry 0 is correct.
List entry 1 is correct.
List entry 2 is correct.

$
```

**2<sup>nd</sup> Update:**

(I believe) I realized the missing piece of [Matheus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5066707/matheus) (considering his Javascript background):

There are no *dynamic arrays* in C (in opposition to Javascript).
Instead, there are arrays with variable size which may be used only in specific situations:

In C:

1. Definition of arrays with variable size in global variables is prohibited. (The compiler needs to know how many bytes to allocate for storage.) This does not exclude something like e.g.
   `int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };`
   because the compiler determines the size from the initializer (on the right hand side of `=`).
2. Declaration of global arrays without explicit size is possible. (The definition with proper size might/must be done somewhere else. The linker will fail if no proper storage definition can be found.)
3. A local variable (inside a function, storage class `auto` but not `static` or `extern`) might be declared as array with size determined at runtime (from a variable). This feature was introduced in C99 but not (yet) in C++ (at least not until C++11 incl.)
4. A function parameter might be declared as array with unknown (or any) size. (This is equal to declaring it as a pointer.)

I found a nice answer about this in [SO: Dynamic array allocation on stack in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441916/dynamic-array-allocation-on-stack-in-c) (which I used to prove my own statements above).

The only supported way to have "dynamic arrays" in C is the usage of the standard library functions `malloc()`/`realloc()`/`free()`. However this is better called "dynamic memory" allocation because this applies to any C type (not only arrays).

*Disclaimer:*

I apologize if I wrote something rubbish about Javascript. I'm the total newbie in Javascript with very less practical experience...

Comment: I'm lunching too, I'll give it a check soon soon

Comment: It worked in my compiler. So weird that I couldn't do `void *values[]` before, now it also compiles this way, but doesn't print what I want yet...

Comment: @Matheus I improved the sample and added a link for demonstration.

Comment: @Matheus I updated my answer and added a fixed version according to your sample code.

Comment: @Matheus Did you notice the missing address operator (`&`) before `value3` in the call of `List_push()` in `main()`? This is intentionally. An array var. provides actually its base address (address of 1st element). The subscript operator (`[]`) is actually a binary operator which takes base address and index and returns reference to the addressed element. (That's why the latter may be applied to pointers also.)

Comment: @Matheus May be, I realized your "missing piece". I added a 2nd update.

Comment: Very thanks for the complete answer! I still find somethings about `**` pointer confusing, I didn't think it could be allocated... so any memory being pointed at can be accessed as an array in C, right? But does it need to be a nested-pointer as `**`, really? Anyways it is working as I much expected