# can we declare a variable inside an array

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, declaration, variable-length-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    int size,i;
    int arr[size];

    printf ("Enter size of array\n");
    scanf ("%d",arr[size]);

    for (i=0; i<=size; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d", arr[size]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't create an array of size determined at runtime this way. `size` must be a literal - not a variable typed in by the user.

Comment: `size` is of size unknown, you must assign value before using to define size of an `array`.

Comment: @kenticent: C supports VLA's

Comment: @TruthSeeker Which standard?

Comment: @kenticent maybe this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Comment: @kenticent, C99, [refer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array)

Comment: @justANewbie I was hinting that VLA is in the first place a C99 feature, which is not obligatory in the further standards. On the Wikipedia it is said, that "In C11, a __STDC_NO_VLA__ macro is defined if VLA is not supported.", therefore I'm asking, which standard does OP use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic array allocation on stack in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441916/dynamic-array-allocation-on-stack-in-c)

Comment: Using a VLA is (IMHO) the least of the problems present in this code.

Answer (score 3):

I have not understood the question but your code is invalid.

Before declaring the variable-length array `arr` the variable `size` must to have already a positive value.  So you need to write at least like

```
int size,i ;

printf ("Enter size of array\n") ; 
scanf ("%d", &size) ;

int arr[size] ;
```

This call of scanf

```
scanf ("%d",arr[size]);
```

does not make any sense, not least because the second argument of the call must be a pointer.

Also, the condition in the for loop must look like

```
for (i=0; i <size; i++) {
          ^^^^^^^
```

And you are trying to output a non-existent element of the array

```
printf ("%d", arr[size]);
```

The valid range of indices for this variable-length array is `[0, size)`.

It seems you mean

```
printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
```

But before outputting elements of the array you need to assign values to them because the array is not initialized and you may not initialize a variable-length array at its declaration.